# Trouble implementing jQuery Masonry in my Rails 3 app

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, jquery-masonry

I'm trying to implement jQuery masonry in my app, but not getting it to work.

I think the problem is that I'm trying to apply it to tables, not divs. Can someone pls take a look and confirm this? how do I fix it?

The page on which I want to apply jquery masonry is just a simple index.html.erb page that shows all the users posts. I want to have these appears in 3 columns, in boxes of varying heights.

Thanks,

Faisal

**POSTS>INDEX.HTML.ERB**

```
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.6.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="/app/assets/javascripts/jquery.masonry.min.js"></script>

<table class="table table-striped">
<script type="text/javascript"> 
$('#container').masonry({
    itemSelector: '.box',
    columnWidth : 100 
});
</script>
<tbody>
<% @posts.each do |post| %>
<tr>
<td>I am a <%= post.title %> getting married in <%= post.job %> in <%= post.location %>, and looking for a <%= post.salary %>. My budget is <%= post.salary %>.</td>
<td><%= time_ago_in_words(post.created_at) %> ago.</td>
</tr>
<% end %>
</tbody>
</table>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Make sure you update "/path/to/jquery.masonry.min.js"  with the actual path to the script

here is a working example I did on the fly http://jsfiddle.net/D7QQU/1/:

```
  <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.6.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="/path/to/jquery.masonry.min.js"></script>
  <style>
    .item {
      width: 220px;
      margin: 10px;
      float: left;
    }
  </style>
  <script> 
    $('#container').masonry({
       itemSelector: '.box',
        columnWidth : 100 
    });
  </script>

  <div id="container">
    <% @posts.each do |post| %>
      <div class="item"> I am a <%= post.title %> getting married in <%= post.job %> in    <%= post.location %>, and looking for a <%= post.salary %>. My budget is <%= post.salary %>.
      <%= time_ago_in_words(post.created_at) %> ago.</div>
    <% end %>
  </div>
```

​From what I've seen, it uses divs instead of table cells.

let me know if you still need help.

**Edit:**

Based on you comment below:

You need to add this to the top of the page using it.  It will find the js in the assets.

If using 3.2 then jquery is in there by default just use the rails jquery:install command

```
<%= javascript_include_tag('jquery.masonry.min') %>
```

Comment: on taking a 2nd look, i think there is something wrong with this...the script is not being activated..if i try deleting the src=jquery.masonry.. line, the page still looks the same. am i missing something? i already updated the path to the masonry script..

Comment: ok, i debugged the page in my browser console; problem is that jquery masonry is not loading. i get a 'failed to load..404 not found' error in the debugger output. the path i'm using is correct: /app/assets/javascripts/jquery.masony.min.js (its a rails 3 app). what could be going wrong here??

Answer (score 2):

If you have the Masonry file in your assets folder, it will be compiled so there is no need to add the javascript_include_tag for it. Also as D3mon-1stVFW mentioned, if you are using Rails 3.2, jQuery is included by default, so no need for that script tag either.

Also, in your script, you should match the class name of the itemSelector with the name of the div element. In your case, your div elements are of class="item", so:

```
<script> 
    $('#container').masonry({
       itemSelector: '.item',
       columnWidth : 100 
    });
</script>
```

And that should get you a bit further in your project.

Comment: I'd also suggest hikmatyar reads up on the basic Masonry documentation: http://masonry.desandro.com/docs/options.html